# WP the_content($more_link_text), strange behavior

Tags: php, wordpress

i using wordpress 3.1.3 to develop custom theme.
it seems my theme has strange behavior.
in the **post** from WP admin i add `<!--more-->` tag to cut the content, and display read more link. and now i want to change the read more text, which the default text is `Continue reading “PAGETITLE” »`

i put this code in the loop of my `index.php` theme.

```
the_content('a');
```

this didn't change the `Continue reading “PAGETITLE” »`, then i try this

```
the_content('');
```

it cleaned the text (which mean for me the code is work). but what im trying to achieve is change that text to `READ MORE`. and this not success.

i think this maybe because of the plugin, but i already try deactive all of the plugin, and still didn't work.

How this can be happen?
I put the code of my `index.php` here http://ideone.com/ya4Sr
can you please help me, maybe there is something wrong with my looping.

Thank you in advance,
GusDe

Comment: I've not had to set `$more` to 0 to get that to work.

Comment: You've got something else going on here, the default "more link" text is just '(more...)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some plugin change my readmore text, and i thing this question not relevant anymore.